# tkinter - display random image from array on button click

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I would like a label to display a random image when a button is clicked.

This is my approach, but it does not work. Any ideas on how to solve welcome.

```
from tkinter import *
import random
window = Tk()

filechoices = ["image1.png", "image2.png", "image3.png"]

filename = PhotoImage(file = random.choice[filechoices]) 

def press():    
    image = Label(window, image=filename).pack()

button1 = Button(window, text="click to see image", command = press)
button1.pack()
```

Comment: What will happend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`random.choice` is a function,not a list.

It should be:

```
filename = PhotoImage(file = random.choice(filechoices))
```

Read [random module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html)

> random.choice(seq)
>   Return a random element from the non-empty sequence seq.

Also,in your code,you haven't used `mainloop()`

Comment: Basically, I'd used [] brackets instead of ()